# Rewrite an Axios call to handle bad data in an array of returned objects

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am working on rewriting my Axios fetch call to handle bad data, like users inputting a series of spaces as the entire value, or in the middle of the string. ("______" or "1._____first word") I have already rewritten the edit form to stop them from adding multiple spaces in the future, but I want to correct the data as I pull it down for display so it does not look like garbage or like there is an error. If the value is nothing but spaces, I would like to clear out the value completely and pass a null value since my form is written to handle nulls.

I have attempted to do this, but I keep hitting roadblocks. I think my issues stems from the regex, which is looking for a string, but the returned results is an array of objects.  I am not sure how to iterate through the array, get rid of the crappy data (multiple spaces), then set everything back to an array that I can past to the seValues function.

Can someone please show me how to do this???

**Here is my current fetch call:**

```
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({} as any);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${detailsUrl + (selectedRecord.id)}`);
        // setValues(res.data.data.);
        const { name, value } = res.data.data;
        setValues({
          ...res.data.data,
          [name]: ((value).replace(/ +(?= )/g, '').trimStart())
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        setValues(error.response.data);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: You should consider if you have this whole idea correct. If those strings are invalid, the server needs to check that they are valid before storing them in the first place so that there are no such "bad" entries coming from the server at all. If that's since been added, but the bad entries got in before, you would do a DB migration (google this term) to update old data instead to ensure it is consistent. What you propose, even if you get it working, is a hack and not the "proper" solution.

Comment: As I said above, I have added validation to ensure the user can no longer input multiple spaces as the value.  I was just looking to handle pre-existing bad data unit we migrate to the new DB and correct the issues with the data.

Comment: It may be better to go straight to the end state. It's worth noting, validation client side does not preclude the requirement to do it on the server side. The latter is a must-have. And the clientside validaton is a nice-to-have. Otherwise anyone can manipulate a request and submit more "bad data". It may be easier to go to the end state, but if you really want to do this in the mean time I can help. So `res.data.data` is an array of objects, where each one contains `name` and `value`?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: And do you want `values` to stay in that array format or do you want it to be transformed to an object where the key is the name and the value the original object for that name?

Comment: yes, I would Like to put it back into an array of objects like it was originally.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to map over the array, effectively editing the `value` of each entry.

```
// Put this above your component

type Value = {
  name: string;
  value: string;
};

// Now in your component...

const [values, setValues] = React.useState<Value[]>([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const res = await axios.get<{ data: Value[] }>(
        `${detailsUrl + selectedRecord.id}`,
      );
      setValues(
        res.data.data.map(({ value, ...other }) => ({
          ...other,
          value: value.replace(/ +(?= )/g, "").trimStart(),
        })),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      setValues(error.response.data);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);
```